# Is there a way to create a rust-polars Series from Vec<u8>?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

how to create a Polars Series from Vec<u8> in rust?

```
use polars::prelude::*;
fn main() {
    let mut col1: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    col1.push(1);
    col1.push(2);
    let s1 = Series::new("col1", col1); // error: the trait `polars::prelude::NamedFrom<Vec<u8>, _>` is not implemented for `polars::prelude::Series`
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your code works if you enable the `dtype-u8` feature like this in `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
polars = { version = "0.26.1", features = ["dtype-u8"] }
```

The requirement was well hidden in the [source code](https://docs.rs/polars-core/0.26.1/src/polars_core/series/iterator.rs.html#30) though.